# Is there any mechanism on GitLab where user can request the access for Private Project?

Tags: gitlab

I want some mechanism, which will have a way to any git user to request access for private project

I can see a way where I (owner) can add any member to the project, But I want process where developers will request the access permission and I as owner will approve that instead of adding it manually

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [request access](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/#request-access-to-a-project) to a group or project. However, the group or project must be visible to the user (must be public or internal visibility).

Requesting access must also be enabled in the group or project settings.

You cannot request access to *private* groups or projects because you can't see them. For private visibility groups or projects, you can only be invited by existing members. However, you can have a private project inside of a public group (or subgroup). So you could make your group public and have users request access to the group (or subgroup) rather than the project directly.

Another alternative would be to have "permission" groups that have no projects. Have these groups public so users can request access. Then [share access to the private project with that group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/share_project_with_groups.html).

Comment: Thank You for this input @sytech , I still need to explore what kind of "Internal" project provides me the security. Like the users which does not have permission to the project, what all activities they can perform on project.